# Ionic phone authentication custom plug in doesn't set firebase.auth().currentUser

Tags: ios, swift, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic-native

previously for my project, I tried creating phone authentication on ionic on android the Recaptcha worked and would send OTP without issues however on ios there were issues with Recaptcha. To fix this issue I created a plug-in to call whenever I need to log in and it works perfectly.

```
import Firebase
import Capacitor


var verification : String = "";

@objc(GetTokenVerification)
public class GetTokenVerification: CAPPlugin {

    @objc func GetT(_ call: CAPPluginCall){
        
        let phone : String = call.getString("phone") ?? "null"

        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phone, uiDelegate: nil) { (verID, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                verification = verID ?? "verification failed"

                call.resolve([
                    "verID" : verification
                ])
            }else{
                print(error!);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @objc func verifyOpt(_ call: CAPPluginCall){
        
        let varif : String = call.getString("varf") ?? "null"
        
        let OTP : String = call.getString("OTP") ?? "null"
        
        let credentials = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: varif, verificationCode: OTP)
        
        var mo = Auth.auth().currentUser;
        print(mo)
        
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials) { (success, error) in
            if(error == nil){
                call.resolve([
                    "passed" : "login made"
                ])
            }else{
                print(error!);
                call.reject("error");
            }
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

However, when setting the firebase security rules I faced an issue that this solution doesn't set the auth information to the auth app locking all of the apps with the security rules is there a custom way to set the auth information for the security rules or a better solution to fixing the original Recaptcha issue

thank you for reading and any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

okay so here is how I fixed the issue I started with passing the UID when signing in to be able to sign in with custom token

```
 let uid = mo?.uid;
                
                call.resolve([
                    "passed" : "login made",
                    "token" : "\(uid ?? "no uid")"
                ])
```

once that is completed I worked on making the creating a firebase function to generate the token

```
export const genAuthTokenIOS = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
      const additionalClaims = {
        phone_number: request.body.phone,
      };
      console.log();
      const uid = request.body.data;
      console.log(uid);
      admin
        .auth()
        .createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
        .then((customToken) => {
          response.status(200).send({ token: customToken });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          response.status(200).send("Failed Login");
        });
    });
  }
);
```

then I used:

```
firebase
              .auth()
              .signInWithCustomToken(data.token)
```

inside ionic and so far the ionic system recognizes that I'm able to sign in without issues and when enabling security rules thankfully it worked

I hope this helps anyone who working on ionic and firebase and needs to implement otp